# Notification is not showing on lockscreen in API26

Tags: android

Here's my notification code. I have tried by `Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC` or `NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC`
But no response on lockscreen . Although in app settings i have allowed lock screen diaplay.

```
public void createNotification(String title,String body) {


        String name = "my_package_channel";
        String id = "my_package_channel_1"; // The user-visible name of the channel.
        String description = "my_package_first_channel"; // The user-visible description of the channel.

        Intent intent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=26) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
                mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            builder.setContentTitle(title)  // required
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sslogo) // required
                    .setContentText(body)//(this.getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        } else {

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            builder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sslogo) // required
                    .setContentText(body)  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notifManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }
```

Comment: Using the above code the notification will show on lock screen in android Oreo and above. Are you able to get push from server properly? and check whether the channel name "my_package_channel" is visible in app notification settings.

Comment: @VigneshK Yes i'm receiving notifications successfully in status bar. I have checked the notification settings and the "Display on Lock screen" is marked . Still i dont get them on lockscreen.